# UIButton background doesn't cover whole view

Tags: ios, ios7, xamarin, xamarin.mac

I use uibutton to display some text in title ,sometimes text is long and I set

```
text.TitleLabel.LineBreakMode = UILineBreakMode.WordWrap;
```

when there are 2 or more lines , background doesn't have enough height
[image]

This is my code for button:

```
text = new UIButton ();
        text.Layer.CornerRadius = 5;
        text.Font = UIFont.FromName ("DIN Condensed", text.Font.PointSize);

        text.SetTitle (Original._hint, UIControlState.Normal);
        text.SizeToFit ();
        text.TitleLabel.LineBreakMode = UILineBreakMode.WordWrap; 

        var rec = new UILongPressGestureRecognizer (() => {     

            text.Frame = new CGRect ((UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow.Frame.Width / 2.0f) - (250 / 2.0f),
                this.Superview.Superview.Superview.Frame.Height / 2.0f,250, text.Frame.Height);
            Animate (0.6f, () => {
                this.Superview.Superview.Superview.AddSubview (text);
            }, () => {
                text.Layer.ZPosition = int.MaxValue;
            });

            viewToremove=text;
        });


        text.SetTitleColor (UIColor.White, UIControlState.Normal);
        text.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Black;

        TargetView.AddGestureRecognizer (rec);
```

Comment: I am not sure but have you checked that font is not cause for this. Check it by changing font to system font.

Comment: yes, font doesn't cause problem :(

Comment: Make your image stretchable, and I would not suggest you to add a gesture recognizer to a button, compose you own UIControl subclass or your own UIView element. Use inset to make enough room for your text

Comment: Does it make any difference to swap around the two lines of code "text.SizeToFit ()" and "       text.TitleLabel.LineBreakMode = ..."   ?   You're currently asking to resize the Button and THEN telling it that, actually, you want to use WordWrap...

Comment: nope. I tried this , but it doesn't make seance @MikeGledhill

Comment: Does your iPhone/iPad screen have AutoLayout turned on ?  If so, do you have a height constraint on this control ?

Comment: Or perhaps you need to modify the value of  "text.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints".

Comment: @MikeGledhill  I have tried , but it doesn't make seance :(

Answer (score 0):

To makes things more clear:

1. Make your image strechable, that can be easily done in the image asset directory by showing slicing [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-image_catalog-1.0/chapters/SlicinganImage.html), this will guarantee that you button will keep the same aspect also in the corners
2. Use button inset, you can do it in IB
   [image: Inset]
   Than I would avoid to use add a gesture recognizer to a UIButton, but I think it will work anyway.

Comment: sorry, it's not clear what image are you talking about?

Comment: the image that you are using as a background

Comment: it is just a color, not image:  text.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Black;

Comment: I see, are you using autolayout? maybe you set a height constraint than force the button to be smaller that its intrinsic content size

Comment: nope, StackLayout. I  modified text.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints property (as @MikeGledhill suggested to me ), but it doesn't make seance

Comment: Don't really know, I don't develop in xamarin but in ObjC, just one last suggestion try to remove SizeToFit. The button should adapt itself based on its content.

Comment: thanks anyway, but it is not good solution to remove SizeToFit, in this case there background color doesn't exist

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem might be cause by your .SizeToFit() method. Generally, you want the .SizeToFit() method to be the last modification of a UIButton, or any other control for that matter. This is to prevent .Frame issues, and text not properly displaying. This probably goes for the background of the UIButton too. So:

- Initialise your button (I usually keep the width static (screenwidth) and set the height to a high number, like 200 or something).
- Modify its properties (including .Title and .BackgroundColor)
- Add a delegate or eventhandler.
- Shrink the button using .SizeToFit();

Let me know if it works. Good luck!

Love and regards,
Björn

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using a 9patch drawable as your background image? Those are designed specifically for situations where you are unsure about the length of the content and require your background image to stretch/shrink to fit. More info [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html#nine-patch)